# Leaflet legends add and remove to connected layerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, legend

I am able to change the legends (legend1 and 2) when adding the overlays (not base maps).
When adding overlay1_name the legend1 shows, but when removing *overlay1_name* the legend1 is not removed. Adding *overlay2_name* removes the legend1 and show legend2, removing overlay2_name the legend2 is not removed. I have like 10 overlays and the legends does not show when activating overlays not connected to the legends but as soon as I have activate overlay1_name or 2 I can not remove the legends from the page without refreshing. It does not help adding any other layer to remove the legends. It's a bit of a pain having legends that does not belong to the data that is shown on the map.
How can this be fixed? Sample code below...

```js
         map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
          // Switch the legends...
        if (eventLayer.name === 'overlay1_name') {
            legend1.addTo(map);
            map.removeControl(legend2);
        } else if (eventLayer.name === 'overlay2_name') {
            legend2.addTo(map);
            map.removeControl(legend1);
        }
    });

    map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer){
        if (eventLayer.name === 'overlay1_name'){
            map.removeControl(legend1);
        } else if (eventLayer.name === 'overlay2_name') {
            map.removeControl(legend2);
    }
    });

        function getColor1(d) {
        switch(d) {
                case 1: return '#2c7bb6';
                case 2: return '#abd9e9';
                case 3: return '#1a9641';
                case 4: return '#a6d96a';
                case 5: return '#ffffbf';
                case 6: return '#fdae61';
                case 7: return '#d7191c';
                default: return '#ffffff';
                }
       };

    var legend1 = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var legdiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        labels = ['0 < 2', '2 < 5', '5 < 10', '10 < 15', '15 < 25', '25 < 50', '> 50' ],
        title = '<b>Total items</b><br>';

        legdiv.innerHTML += title;
    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        legdiv.innerHTML +=
            '<i style="background:' + getColor1(grades[i]) + '"></i> ' +
            (grades[i] ? labels[i] + '<br>' : '+');
    }

    return legdiv;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the map.on('overlayremove' function) I was able to get the result I wanted. I changed the above code sample if anyone else is looking for similar...